# Can't place an annotation on ggplot - R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following dataset:

```
library(tidyverse)
the_dates <- c("2020-08-01","2020-08-02","2020-08-03","2020-08-04")
the_dates <- as.Date(the_dates)
solno <- c(3,4,2,3)
```

I try to create a line chart with an annotation. Since I don't know exactly what will be values to place the annotation, I tried the `Inf` trick:

```
dataex <- data.frame(the_dates, solno)
dataex %>% ggplot(aes(the_dates, solno)) + geom_line() +
  annotate("text",x = -Inf, y= Inf, label = "See me")
```

But I get this error message `Error: Invalid input: date_trans works with objects of class Date only`

I don't know what I am doing wrong. Please, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hello @Ronak Shah, I want to place the annotation in the top left.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is that x-axis is date class. So try this code. As there is not infinite values for dates you can play aroun minimum values in your variable `the_dates`. Here the code:

```
#Data
dataex <- data.frame(the_dates, solno)
#Code
dataex %>% ggplot(aes(the_dates, solno)) + geom_line() +
  annotate("text",x = min(dataex$the_dates), y= Inf, label = "See me",hjust=-0.1,vjust=1)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Duck for the answer, works fine!. Just a question, is it possible to use percentages as relatives positions? Like (x=0%,y=80%)?

Comment: @Manu Hi Manu, you could use `x=0,y=0.8` only if both of your axis were in a scale between 0-1 otherwise you will get similar issues like those you showed!